# macOS port forwarding for remote ssh login

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, router, port-forwarding

I want to do remote ssh logins from outside my network to a server (macOS Sierra) on my LAN, using a port other than 22. ([I hear](https://askubuntu.com/a/716190) that it improves security to use a port other than the default. Is this true?)

I have successfully configured my router ([Cisco RV325](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/rv325-dual-gigabit-wan-vpn-router/index.html), which has a fixed WAN IP address of, say, 99.99.99.99) so that I can log in remotely to the server (at static LAN IP address 12.0.0.123) on port 22, like so:

```
$ ssh USERNAME@99.99.99.99 -p 22
```

This works fine. I now want to be able log in through another port (let's say 60022) like so:

```
$ ssh USERNAME@99.99.99.99 -p 60022
```

I don't understand how to forward traffic from port 60022 to 22. Is this something that I should do in the router, or in the local server? The router's "Port Range Forwarding Table" config does allow packets of a given port range to be forwarded to a particular IP, but it doesn't appear to allow me to translate from one port to another.

If it's supposed to happen in the server, I don't understand how to do that. And how do I get macOS to even start listening on port 60022?

I've tried unsuccessfully adapting [these Ubuntu instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716184/how-to-ssh-into-a-server-running-on-a-home-network-behind-a-router) to the Mac. I've tried using `pfctl` to set up forwarding:

```
$ echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 60022 -> 127.0.0.1 port 22
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 60022
" | sudo pfctl -f -
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
$
```

This doesn't appear to open port 60022, since (1) the port doesn't show up when I do `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN` and (2) the connection is refused when I sit at the server and try to login:

```
$ ssh USERNAME@127.0.0.1 -p 60022 -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 60022.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 60022: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 60022: Connection refused
$
```

Whereas logging in on port 22 works fine:

```
$ ssh USERNAME@127.0.0.1 -p 22 -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
Password:
$
```

In summary:

1. How do I tell macOS to start listening on port 60022?
2. How do I tell macOS to translate port 60022 to 22?
3. Any good intro/tutorials out there on how to do this?
4. Should I even bother trying to forward to 60022 (for example), or is it safe enough to use the default port 22?

Comment: You usually do it at the exact same place you did it for port 22.  On the router.

Comment: Moving `ssh` to a nonstandard port doesn't make it significantly more secure, it just cuts down on the amount of random password-guessing attacks you'll get from bots and whatnot. If anyone is actually interested in breaking into your server (as opposed to just randomly scanning for easy targets), it'll do almost nothing to keep them out. That said, I consider cutting down on background noise from bot attacks to be worthwhile, so I do recommend using a nonstandard port; just don't mistake this for a real security measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @yoonix suggested, you can accomplish the desired goal entirely in the router, without tinkering with the server (macOS or otherwise). The summary questions #1 and #2 (and even the title of the post) are perhaps a bit misleading. As to summary question #4, see the comment by @Gordon Davisson.

To accomplish the goal, set up the router as follows:

1. Log in to the RV325 config page with your browser. Select "Setup" > "Port Address Translation".
2. Under the "Port Address Translation Table" click the "Service Management..." button. In the popup window click "Add", then type in a service name (your handy nickname for this port address translation setup), choose "TCP" from the popup menu, then type in the External Port (60022) and the Internal Port (22). Click "Save", and dismiss the popup window.
3. Back in the "Port Address Translation Table", click "Add". Select your service name from the popup menu, type in the forwarding IP address (12.0.0.123 in the example), and check the Status box to enable it. Click "Save".
4. Go to "Firewall" > "Access Rules" and click the "Service Management..." button. In the popup window  click "Add", then type in a service name (your nickname for this Access Rule), and enter the external port number (or range of port numbers) that you'd like to open (60022-60022 for this example). Click "Save", and dismiss the popup window.
5. Finally, in "Access Rules" click "Add". Select "Allow" and the service name you created above. Leave "Source IP" and "Destination IP" as "Any". Click "save".

From now on the router will take care of the necessary forwarding and port translation, so that doing `ssh USERNAME@99.99.99.99 -p 60022` will send you right to the login daemon on the desired server at 12.0.0.113 .